# A basic confusion in the proof of Picard's existence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In the proof of Picard's existence theorem of solution of ODE I don't understand the following step:

Once it proves that the limit of uniformly convergent series is a continuous function then it tries to prove that this limit satisfies the integral equation. I think uniform convergence and lipschitz is enough to prove it. But, in some book the following lines in the proof. I don't understand the use of it.

Since $x_n \rightarrow x$ uniformly on $I$, and $|x_n(t) - x_0|\leq b \quad \forall n$ and for $t \in I^+$, it follows that
$$|x(t)| \leq b \quad\forall t \in I^+.$$

Here $I =[t_0 -h, t_0 +h]$ and $I^+ = [t_0, t_0 +h]$

My question is why  $|x(t)| \leq b \quad \forall t \in I^+$ is needed. I think the notations are clear from the context, otherwise I have to explicitly mention them.

Comment: Hard to know for sure without knowing how the proof continues. Generally, the statement of Picard's theorem involves a certain rectangle in the $(t,x)$ plane. We make an assumption about the behavior of right hand side  within this rectangle, and prove that the solution exists, is unique, and *stays in the rectangle* for some interval of time. This looks like the proof of the latter claim.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier.: It is there in the pdf (page 18-19, top of page 19). http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111104031/

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier.: What you are saying has been proved separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo: the author meant $|x(t)-x_0|\le b$.

And this inequality is used in the next sentence: "Now the Lipschitz condition on $f$ implies..." The Lipschitz condition for $f$ was assumed to hold on the rectangle $R$, so we must check that the things  we put into $f$ are within this rectangle.

Comment: But, this has been proved earlier. See middle of page 18. And for that we don't need uniform convergence. pointwise convergence is enough as the rectangle is a closed set. Am I correct ?